# Salesforce Flow - Is it possible to update a dynamic field?

Tags: visual-workflow, dynamic, field-mapping, fielddefinition, object-relational-mapping

I currently have a Record-Triggered Flow on Lead object which is not really complex, but with a lot of possible issue, and I'm pretty sure it can be improved.

This Flow is basically updating some "milestone" date fields when a Lead status is changed.
For example, we have :

- When status is updated to "Call Attempt 1", set the "CallAttempt1Date__c" field to "today()"
- When status is updated to "Lost", set the "LostDate__c" field to "today()"
  And we have 6 other statuses, so 6 other different workflow (but not so different, as the process remains the same, with different fields to update, according to the status).

If I would have absolutely no problem to do it with an Apex Trigger, using a Custom Metadata Type, containing a mapping between my status (LeadStatus__c), a Metadata Relationship(Field Definition) relating to the field to update (FieldToUpdate__c) and the value to set in this field (FieldValue__c),  and this kind of code:

```
List<myMappingMetadata__mdt> mappingList = [SELECT Id, FieldToUpdate__r.QualifiedApiName, FieldValue__c, 
                                            FROM CMD02_LeadStatusUpdateFieldValueMapping__mdt
                                            WHERE Object__c = 'Lead'
                                            AND LeadStatus__c = :newStatus];

for(myMappingMetadata__mdt mapping : mappingList) {
    myLead.put(mapping.FieldToUpdate__r.QualifiedApiName, mapping.FieldValue__c);
}
```

However, Apex Trigger is not an option (company rules), and I'd like to know if this is something feasible with a Flow (I'm pretty confident it is)?

Comment: Can you create an invokable class that a flow can call? or is it all apex that's banned by your company?

Comment: I forgot to say that it's a before trigger flow, so I think I can't call a invokable class.
But I guess that if I can't do it in a Flow, it's the best option.

Comment: I think you should use a trigger and use apex. I am unsure what it requires to convenience your business to avoid complicating this with the flows. It would be best if you were using best tool for the job. This sounds like triggers and using Apex is the best choice here.

Comment: the apex sobject class `put` method is your friend here to do dynamic field updates